# Why does HTML5 input of type number not work or works sporadically in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to get decimals to work in a input field of type number. To implement this I'm trying to modify the step attribute.

```
 <input name="aNumberInput" type="number" min="10000" max="400000" step=".001"  id="with-step"/>
```

I've found the implementation in IE10 doesn't work, the validation is completely sporadic. For example, use the following jsFiddle and try inputting 11111.232, then try 11111.222. For some reason the .232 validates but the .222 does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/4PQn9/

Comment: color me surprised that IE didn't implement a feature correctly.

Comment: Could this have something to do with binary representations of floating point numbers? (Not helpful to your use case, but might explain why it's broken.)

Comment: The jsfiddle does not correspond to the code in the question. The `pattern` attribute is not valid for `input type=number`.

Comment: my apologies with the incorrect jsfiddle link, new one up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing this .. does this happen in

Browser Mode: **IE10**

Document Mode: **Standards**

???

**IE10** does support the input number type **but it does not show increment / decrement buttons.**

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx**

check browser support:

**http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number**

list of supported input types in IE:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534700%28v=vs.85%29.aspx**

**UPDATE**

looks like this was also asked here:

**[HTML Number Input removes decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993302/html-number-input-removes-decimal-point)**

**[Force decimal point instead of comma in HTML5 number input (client-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332/force-decimal-point-instead-of-comma-in-html5-number-input-client-side?rq=1)**

**http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/**

Comment: I see that it "partially supports" and evidently that partially is that it doesn't handle steps very well as is evident in my question.

Comment: @chuckp16 also look at this StackOverflow question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993302/html-number-input-removes-decimal-point .. looks like it might also depend on browser and OS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178332/force-decimal-point-instead-of-comma-in-html5-number-input-client-side?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993302/html-number-input-removes-decimal-point found my answer in this link thank you

Comment: @chuckp16 - awesome .. can you mark my answer as answered please.. since i have **HTML Number Input removes decimal point** in my answer :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993302/html-number-input-removes-decimal-point -

Answer (score 1):

input type number is not fully supported in IE10(not supported in IE9 and below) as it it supported in FF or Chrome.

Check this docs on microsoft site
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**update:-** support of input type number across browsers
http://caniuse.com/input-number

Answer (score 0):

To allow number input types in IE10 to use decimals, you can use the "any" value for step which will change it from the default of "1".
http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html

```
<input name="aNumberInput" type="number" min="10000" max="400000" step="any"  id="with-step"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C2HU2/

My goal was to maintain min-max, number validation, and allow a decimal/float value to be submitted to the form. This accomplishes that for me. The stepper in chrome increments by 1 which will suffice as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar problem. However, IE doesn't have support for input type="number" but you can use jQueryUI Spinner widget. It is very simple to use and it has many API's that friendly for developers.

Demo of jQuery-UI Spinner:
https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

API of jQuery-UI Spinner
https://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-change